# Rails iterative command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm searching for a method or a possibility, which getting two date as string or whatever and for each month send a command.

For example, I have these dates, d1= "10.05.2016" and d2= "12.05.2018", the method DurationInMonth computes the number of month and returns 25.

The method DurationInMonth is implemented.

Just I need, is a possibility that the "create method" calls and every time with the new param

```
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
   "booking"=>{"employee_id"=>"9","started_on"=>"16.11.2015",
   "finished_on"=>"30.11.2016", "person_month"=>"0", 
   "package_id"=>"65"}, "commit"=>"Absenden"}

   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
   "booking"=>{"employee_id"=>"9","started_on"=>"01.12.2015",
   "finished_on"=>"31.12.2016", "person_month"=>"0", 
   "package_id"=>"65"}, "commit"=>"Absenden"}
```

et cetera

I hope you understand me

```
def durationInMonth(d1=nil, d2=nil)
  d1 = d1 ? d1 : self.started_on
  d2 = d2 ? d2 : self.finished_on
  d1 = Date.strptime(d1, '%d.%m.%Y') 
  d2 = Date.strptime(d2, '%d.%m.%Y') 

  month_number = (d2.year * 12 + d2.month) - (d1.year * 12 + d1.month)
  month_number.divmod(12)

  return 1 if month_number == 0
  return month_number + 1 # e.g. 06.11.15 and 10.12.15  = 1 +  1
end
```

Comment: How is the `duration` of the dates `d1` and `d2` calculated to 14?

Comment: This is a convention and not the main point, but FYI  01.11.12 -> 02.12.12 is for me two month

Comment: We need to understand your algorithm in order to help you. Can I assume that the duration of your example "10.05.2016" and "12.05.2018" is 25?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this:

```
def duration_in_month(d1, d2, format = '%d.%m.%Y')
  d1 = Date.strptime(d1, format)
  d2 = Date.strptime(d2, format)

  (d2.year - d1.year) * 12 + (d2.month - d1.month) + 1
end

duration_in_month('01.11.2012', '02.12.2012')
#=> 2

duration_in_month('10.05.2016', '12.05.2018')
#=> 25
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand me and my problem :P  The durationInMonth do what I want, but what I want, is, if I click auf submit icon, it must send e.g 25 the command  `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
   "booking"=>{"employee_id"=>"9","started_on"=>"01.12.2015",
   "finished_on"=>"31.12.2016", "person_month"=>"0", 
   "package_id"=>"65"}, "commit"=>"Absenden"}` and every one with a new Interval